# How to prevent the right click "Save as image" or "open image in New Tab" on wordpress?

Tags: java, php, jquery, css, wordpress

I know that many asked for DISABLE RIGHT CLICK option on wordpress, I'm not a great supporter of right click option, it's a must have on a website. On the other hand, it would be good to protect direct media link and image save option on wordpress.

Advanced users can definitely find a way to access the media or attachments, it's hard to control them, but my query is to prevent the image save options for the normal users. Prevent the image stealing from the normal users (who use simple -- RIGHT CLICK > SAVE AS IMAGE option).

Use cases : Lets assume you are an artist posting your unique works (as images > JPG/PNG and even GIF image) on the website, professional photographer posting original unique images on the website.

I have seen several methods online to prevent the right click save as image option, nothing worked so far. So please help me to solve this issue.

Thanks in advance.

NOTE: Check www.animaticons.co website, they've hosted their gif images, but you (normal user) cannot download the images from the web. This is the exact solution i'm looking for. Thanks.

Comment: Hold on, so you want to prevent the right click save, but not disable right click?  Do mean that in a global sense, or at all?  Because afaik, the menu that is shown on right click is out of the control of javascript.  That's a browser program responsibility.

Comment: Even if you manage this, the user can get to the media in the Page Info dialog (in Mozilla), or can use the system’s screen shot capability.  If it’s on the web, it’s not under your control anymore.

Comment: I'm an artist who wants to get paid for my work.. let's see.. what you're saying is that instead of sticking a huge watermark over the image, you want to feed my browser the actual image but if I'm a mere mortal, you want to prevent me from getting it? Man, have you any idea how many normal users ask me how to get them stuff from net on a daily basis? Your solution isn't fool-proof against "normal" users.

Comment: @Taplar -- You didn't get my question, if you have seen the attached link, you could have got my point, Rajan Benipuri answered my query well. it's not about RIGHT CLICK menu option, it's about the image placement, which will avoid the SAVE AS IMAGE option. As per his words, the image is saved as background on a DIV.

Comment: @N.B -- I'm not looking for foolproof method (nothing is foolproof, anything is hackable online), just trying to see how the images could be kept hidden behind a layer from the normal users. That's it. So in simple terms, looking for option which is not as easy as SAVE AS IMAGE and get direct access. I hope you get it.. BTW, watermark is definitely a good option, but it again has its pros and cons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We (normal user as per your question) can't download images shown in your given url is because they are not showing images inside a normal `<img>` tag, rather they are showing the image as `background-image` of the containing div. You can's save or open image in new tab for background images.

Comment: Thanks a ton for the response, this is the one method i wanted to know. I haven't used CSS much before, so could you direct me to the right TUTORIAL (youtube/blog) to learn about it. 

I guess i've seen some websites used it to hide their logo image element. 

Any cues on the css code to be used for this and if possible kindly include a generic code... cheers.

Comment: Glad to know I could help. By the way, this is not essentially to hide any image or logo but for other styling reasons. To protect your images from unauthorized uses, I suggest you to use watermarks. By the way to know more about CSS `background-image` property [Read this article](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-image.asp)

Comment: Thanks again for the quick response. I guess i should start learning CSS basics. I guess If I'm right, I should use my image as a background on DIV for this to work. Also, just curious to know whether i need to have an overlay image (i.e. transparent image layer above the background?) or just the background image would do the trick. 

Thanks a lot for answering my question. cheers.

A SAMPLE SYNTAX WOULD BE GREAT...:) 

i.e. image1.jpg is my resource, how could it be placed as the background on my DIV -- Syntax??

Comment: @ram I suggest you to read the basics of CSS style. As far as SYNTAX is concerned, it should be `<div style="background-image: image1.jpg; width: 100px; height: 100px;">` Here, I have added `width` and `height` because the `background-image` will not affect dimension of a div. You can change it as per your requirements and in future try to use CSS as an external file or all the styles inside `<style></style>` tag inside your <head></head>` Also, accept the answer if it helped.

Comment: thanks a lot for the great response..i could get some understanding from your response. I'll read the basics of css before moving further, thanks a ton..

Answer (score 3):

Why not just watermark your images? The problem is when it's possible for the client to display an image it's also possible to download or screenshot the image.

And do not try to differ between normal users and advanced users - it's like saying "Maybe a hacker is able to attack my website, but not a normal user so it's secure."

Comment: There it is, the only possible correct answer. Up you go buddy!

Answer (score 0):

They made them 'background' images on that website (CSS: backgound-image).  But it's  really trivial to download through the browser's inspector (F12).  Or a [browser extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/image-downloader/cnpniohnfphhjihaiiggeabnkjhpaldj).

If they're on the page, they're downloaded, whether in memory or a temporary folder.

If you're protecting against downloads, then only host low quality image samples publicly, and put the high quality ones behind a payment gateway (or whatever hoop the user has to jump through).

Answer (score 0):

Try this code this will remove the whole right click context menu.

```
document.addEventListener('contextmenu', event => event.preventDefault());
```

Answer (score 0):

The second question - how to disable direct download of any file when you know its url - is a great one! I have tried for days to find a solution for my website and you will find it above.

## Contextual menu: its everything or nothing

To prevent right click, you can use plugins like the excellent "Disable right click for WP" for example. But it will entirely deactivate the contextual menu. The contextual menu being a part of the webkit of the browser, you won't be able to deactivate only one of its items. It will be everything or nothing.

## Preventing files downloads when a direct link is used

More important, to prevent direct linking to your pictures, you can only do this BEFORE PHP is involved to display your website, so ONLY AT THE WEB SERVER level. You need to tell the webserver to forbid any image access not made directly by itself (to display the image of your website).
To do this you need to play with the webserver configuration file: ***.htaccess*** located at the root level of your standard WordPress installation.

## Editing .htaccess

1. open ***/.htaccess***
2. Add the following code before the `#BEGIN Wordpress` line and adapt it with your website domain name knowing that the following code is made for a website located at *[www.example.com](http://www.example.com)*. This sample of code is blocking direct downloads of every .txt, .mp4, .jpg and .png files. If you want to make another choice, just change *txt|mp4|jpg|png* in the code:

   ```
   <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https://(www\.)?example\.com [NC]
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https://(www\.)?example\.com.*$ [NC]
   RewriteRule \.(txt|mp4|jpg|png)$ - [F]
   # or, much better, less radical, you can replace the last RewriteRule by the following one, to display always the same page or image from your website, changing *https://www.example.com/link-to-page-or-image* to the address of the page or image you'd like to display when someone is trying to download a file using a direct link :
   # RewriteRule \.(txt|mp4|jpg|png)$ https://www.example.com/link-to-page-or-image [L]

   </IfModule>
   ```

## Testing

1. Empty your browser cache.
2. Try to reach an image of your website entering the direct link to that image in your browser address bar (in WP for example go to your *Media Library*, select any image - a .jpg one if you adapted the previous code to prevent direct downloading of .jpg images - and use the copy button to copy image URL then open a browser new window and paste the copied url in your browser address bar). You should see that the image can't be downloaded by this way.
3. Visit to your website : all the images are displayed and every functionalities involving images and direct links (lightbox...) should still be working perfectly because only the webserver has the right to call them.
4. If the results looks perfect to you, don't forget to save a copy of the edited ***.htaccess*** file on your desktop for example (removing the dot if your are working on Mac or Linux machine to keep it visible) since Wordpress, in some circumstances, could regenerate that file without the added code. My advice on this point: when you have changed any settings in WP and mainly the some related to permalinks (adding some extensions could also involved ***.htaccess*** edition), take a look at the ***.htaccess*** file's content to check if the added code is still there... Or add it again.

Enjoy!