# Is it possible to disable copying/cut/download/drag image in wordpress?

Tags: css, wordpress

I want to disable copy, drag & download image in wordpress. I read a lot of posts about content theft. I dont want someone to steal the images i post on my blog posts in wordpress.... **Is there any plugin to stop it? **Or is it possible to stop it with php, or css code?****

i tried to disable right click in wordpress but still images can be dragged and open it in other tab and download. So it is useless. Is there any other way to stop image copying/download/drag to other tab.

Comment: Just a note: no, it's not possible to disable this entirely. You can use `pointer-events`, as suggested by an answer, but even that doesn't stop people who want to nab your image. If you show it in someone's browser, it's on their computer and they can save it.

Comment: Many sites overlay an image with a *1px transparent image* and stretch that to full width/height. Upon download/drag/etc, that transparent image gets saved. But it is a bandaid, it won't prevent ppl from opening DevTools and use that to download everything. Right-click blockers work fine, but right-click-blocker-unblockers work just as good. If you don't want something downloaded, just don't post it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to prevent the right click "Save as image" or "open image in New Tab" on wordpress?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49244823/how-to-prevent-the-right-click-save-as-image-or-open-image-in-new-tab-on-wor)

Answer (score 1):

This is the CSS to add, which will prevent rightclicking on the image:

```
img {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

Further reading: https://betterstudio.com/wordpress-tutorials/disable-right-click-on-images-wordpress/

Comment: Be aware that this does not really stop anyone from getting access to the image or downloading it, there is just no way to do that. There's no encrypted streams for images or something. So this might deter some people, but it won't 'solve' the issue.